# How do I calculate average? and What does per 100 word mean?

Tags: arithmetic, average

`- 295 letter(s) 
 - 70 word(s)
 - 3 sentence(s)`

How do I calculate ?

1. **Average number of letters per 100 words.**
2. **Average number of sentences per 100 words.**

I know that:

> Average = total value / No. of value

SO, Average letters = **`295 / words`** ? is that how we do it? what about per 100 words?
Can someone explain it to me?

(PS I am not good at maths. Thankyou for your time.)

Comment: You just multiply the average by 100. Also I don't think MathSE is correct place for such question. (I didn't downvote your question)

Answer (score 1):

Average letters per words=295/70=4.21
Average letters per 100 words=421.
average sentences per words=3/70=0.0428
average sentences per 100 words=4.28